# How to access metaData of workout in healthkit using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, hksamplequery

I am able to get  basic data of activities like `duration`, `totalEnergyBurned` etc.
But how can I access meta data like `HKWasUserEntered` `startDate` ?

Here is my code so far

```
var predicate = HKQuery.predicateForWorkoutsWithWorkoutActivityType(HKWorkoutActivityType.Cycling)
 let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: HKWorkoutType.workoutType(), predicate: predicate, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor])
    { (sampleQuery, results, error ) -> Void in

        if let queryError = error {
            print( "There was an error while reading the samples: \(queryError.localizedDescription)")
        }
        else
        {
            print(results!)
          for samples: HKSample in results! {
                var workout: HKWorkout = (samples as! HKWorkout)
                print("workout Distance is \(workout.totalDistance)")
                print("workout Energy Burned is \(workout.totalEnergyBurned)")
                print("workout Duration in seconds is \(workout.duration)")

            }
        }
        completion(results,error)
    }

    executeQuery(sampleQuery)
```

When I print `results` I am getting this in return

> [ (46)  "Health" (9.3.2) metadata: {
>       HKWasUserEntered = 1;
>   } 2016-07-18 10:58:00 +0500 2016-07-18 11:58:00 +0500]

so basically how can I fetch `HKWasUserEntered` and dates from this ?

Answer (score 1):

I understood how work with metadata.

```
            if let metadata = workout.metadata {
                if let  mataTemperature = metadata[HKMetadataKeyWeatherTemperature] {
                    if let quantityTemperature = mataTemperature as? HKQuantity {
                        let celsius = quantityTemperature.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.degreeCelsius())
                        print(celsius)
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `metadata` dictionary property on `HKSample`. You could print the value like this, for example:

`print("workout was user entered \(workout.metadata[HKWasUserEntered])")`

Comment: I am getting this error value of type [HKworkout] has no member `metadata`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
print("was user entered --> \(workout.metadata?[HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered])")
```